# css, body background image top on samsung tablet / Moodle

Tags: html, css, moodle

Problem occur  on  Sambungs tables. I have background image set on body.
Css look like

```
html, body{
  background: url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-position: top; // i tried also cover, fixed etc
}
```

Webpage is quite high, like over 2000px , where background image takes first 600px, and it could be fine for me, but when i click to hide some box on the bottom of the page, background will automatically appear at the visible part of a screen and it will be eareased from the top of the page. Page isn't realoading during hiding boxes on page, that's why I don't really know how to solve this problem.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to input background into div#wrapper. It solved my problem with rendering of background image